# Powershell- Getting value from a connection string

Tags: xml, powershell, ssis

I am trying to extract the connection manager from xml code but cant seem to get it to return. Below code loops through a folder and returns the sql logic and should return the connection manager but i cant get that working. Any suggestions as to where i have gone wrong.  The XML code would like this but i am trying to automate it to search through all packages and not just one instance.

[image: XML sample]

```
$folderPath = "Z:\Database\SSIS\Test"
    $namespace = @{
        DTS = "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
        SQLTask = "www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask"
        DTSConnection = "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts/Connection"
    }
    
    # Get all files in the folder with the .dtsx file extension
    $packageFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter "*.dtsx" -Recurse
    
    foreach ($file in $packageFiles) {
        Write-Output "Processing file $($file.FullName)"
    
        # Load the package XML file
        $xml = [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName)
    
        # Extract the SQL statement from the package XML
        $sqlStatementSource = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $namespace -XPath "//DTS:ObjectData/SQLTask:SqlTaskData/@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
    
        # Extract the connection string from the package XML
        $connectionString = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $namespace -XPath "//DTS:ObjectData/DTS:ConnectionManagers/DTS:ConnectionManager/DTS:ObjectData/DTS:ConnectionManager/@DTSConnection:ConnectionString" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
    
        Write-Output "SQL Statement: $sqlStatementSource"
        Write-Output "Connection String: $connectionString`n"
    }
```

Edit: XML code as text:

```
    <DTS:ConnectionManagers>
<DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[Test]" DTS:CreationName="OLEDB" DTS:DTSID="{0C0B353E-C2D5-4CEE-B6D0-8F97B030C8F4}" DTS:ObjectName="Test">
<DTS:ObjectData>
<DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:ConnectRetryCount="1" DTS:ConnectRetryInterval="5" DTS:ConnectionString="Data Source=Test\PROD;Initial Catalog=MM;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"/>
</DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
<DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[Flat File Connection Manager]" DTS:CreationName="FLATFILE" DTS:DTSID="{0B7B5750-8D58-4455-A008}" DTS:ObjectName="Flat File Connection Manager">
<DTS:ObjectData>
<DTS:ConnectionManager DTS:Format="Delimited" DTS:LocaleID="6153" DTS:HeaderRowDelimiter="_x000D__x000A_" DTS:RowDelimiter="" DTS:TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" DTS:CodePage="1252" DTS:ConnectionString="\\galbswebwp00002\DatawatchDropZone\MBUD_MONTHLYSHIP.TXT">
<DTS:FlatFileColumns>
<DTS:FlatFileColumn DTS:ColumnType="Delimited" DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x000D__x000A_" DTS:MaximumWidth="2000" DTS:DataType="129" DTS:TextQualified="True" DTS:ObjectName="Column 0" DTS:DTSID="{C95AF712-EDC8-40DB-B031-D223FCEDD8E5}" DTS:CreationName=""/>
</DTS:FlatFileColumns>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
</DTS:ObjectData>
</DTS:ConnectionManager>
</DTS:ConnectionManagers>
```

Comment: Can you paste your xml as text - I’m replying on a phone and I’m not going to type all of that into tio.run to test your sample code :-).

Comment: @mclayton yes i will edit post and include it now for you.

Comment: Can you also include the namespace declarations? If I try to convert your string to an xml document I get ```Error: "'DTS' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position
2.```  because there's no namespaces defined in the fragment

Comment: @mclayton I have update the xml to include logic which comes before it. I hope this is what you are expecting